# csh passing $* to Perl script not working

Tags: perl, csh

I am writing a shell script in csh, and one of its functions is to execute a Perl script that takes in arguments.

The csh script itself takes in command line arguments (stored as space-separated values in `$*`), and I pass this to the Perl script.

My issue is that when I run:

`perl myscript.pl --args $*`

the Perl script only gets the first argument in `$*`. However, if I run `echo $*` from within the csh script, it correctly prints out all the arguments.

There can be any number of arguments passed (thus I cannot store my arguments in static variables and pass them through).

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Comment: What does this output: `perl -e 'print "@ARGV"' $*`?

Comment: ./script.csh arg1 arg2

outputs: arg1 arg2

Comment: Im using getopts on my perl script, so placing -e converts these to flags I believe?

Comment: So passing `$*` works just fine. Whatever module you use to process the arguments, you aren't using it properly. I suggest checking the docs.

Comment: im using:

`GetOptions ("args=s@"=>\@my_args);`

in perl to capture the array. Is this incorrect?

Comment: @user1220086 Qtax is asking to show how your system parses the command line objects.  We want you to run a, simple, one program: `perl -e 'print "@ARGV"' $*` The -e simply tells perl to find our script on the command line. From inside your csh script, so as to load up $*, run this command and post here what the output is.

Comment: @user1220086 Oops, I see where you did that, sorry.
Your code appears correct but it appears -args would need to preceed each element of your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote `$*` in your csh script:

```
perl myscript.pl --args "$*"
```

Here is `myscript.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;
use Data::Dumper;

my %opt;
GetOptions(\%opt, 'args=s');
print Dumper(\%opt);
```

Here is how I call it:

```
script.csh arg1 arg2

$VAR1 = {
          'args' => 'arg1 arg2'
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the arguments to end up in an array without putting --args before each, you can use Getopt::Long's experimental multiple values syntax:

```
GetOptions("args=s{,}" => \@my_args);
```

See https://metacpan.org/module/Getopt::Long#Options-with-multiple-values